# How do I get a cygwin script to output to file?

Tags: cygwin

I need to get the results of this to output to a file, but have no idea what command to use - any ideas please?

```
input="/cygdrive/c/dev/test/need_file_size.csv"
trunkRoot=/cygdrive/c/dev/trunk/test-trunk
outputFile=/cygdrive/c/temp/findSizes.log

while read row; do
        class=$(echo $row | cut -f 2 -d ",")
        find $trunkRoot/ -name "${class}.java" | xargs ls -long          
done < "$input"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input="/cygdrive/c/dev/test/need_file_size.csv"
trunkRoot=/cygdrive/c/dev/trunk/test-trunk
outputFile=/cygdrive/c/temp/findSizes.log

while read row; do
        class=$(echo $row | cut -f 2 -d ",")
        find $trunkRoot/ -name "${class}.java" | xargs ls -long >> filename          
done < "$input"
```

Notice the append to `filename` or run the script and do it

```
./myscript >> filename
```

Comment: I ended up doing that in the end after some more better googling - I didn't expect it to be quite so simple! Thanks though :)